# Delimiting a macro argument with the macro itself

Tags: macros, programming

Any command sequence can be used to delimit a macro parameter. Even one that has not been defined. For example:

```
\def\YY#1,#2\@@{#1,#2}

\YY123,2345\@@
```

will happily work, even if the macro `\@@` has not been defined.

In the LaTeX source there is an unusual macro, where the name of the macro itself was used as a delimiter. In simple terms the example below works, with no errors.

```
\def\XX#1,#2\XX{#1,#2}

\XX12,13\XX
```

**Does this offer any memory or speed advantage or any other advantage for that matter?**

Short MWE for experimentation is listed below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\def\YY#1,#2\@@{#1,#2}
\YY123,2345\@@

\def\XX#1,#2\XX{#1,#2}
\XX12,13\XX

\makeatother
\end{document}
```

Comment: @SamB: I don't think that macro tokens in the parameter text require a hash entry. There are never looked-up. The `\@nil` (undefined) and `\@nnil` (contains `\@nil`) are often used by LaTeX as end-markers.

Comment: @Martin: I'd agree, as the hash table only contains things which are defined. Perhaps Yiannis might give us a clue as to the real case in hand, which might be enlightening!

Comment: This construction is used in `ltcntrl.dtx` for `\@removeelement`. It's also used in `ltfssdcl.dtx` in a rather brain-melting definition for `\in@`.

Comment: @Martin @Joseph @Sam Please check `\def\in@@##1#1##2##3\in@@` in `ltfssdcl.dtx`.

Comment: Another thing I have seen done is to change the catcode of some character to something odd (I think I saw `Q` being given catcode 3) and use that as the delimiter. Looking at `\if@`, the comments seem wrong. Maybe I'm missing something, but I do not see any expansion.

Comment: @TH. You are right, no expansion. @Yiannis if the item you are searching for contains braces (e.g. `Hef{}feron`), then you _must_ use strings. The only constraint on the delimiter is that it does not appear in `#1#2`. Also, that version of `\in@` fails in some cases e.g. `\in@false  \in@{baba}{cba} \show\ifin@`.

Comment: `\def\YY#1,#2\@@{#1,#2}` does indeed work but the user cannot (himself define and later) use `\@@` within arguments of `\YY`. Perhaps the authors of `\in@@` hoped that nobody would via `\let` rename `\in@@` and then redefine it. Perhaps they also hoped that nobody would nest calls to `\in@@` witin arguments of `\in@@`. Under this assumption you can use the control sequence token itself as delimiter/as "sentinel token"/as forbidden token which must not occur within the argument... Perhaps the control sequence token itself was chosen also as delimiter in order not to block another macro-name.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

With inconclusive comments, I decided to look again for an explanation in the TeXBook, but with no success. However this led to another example. In the answer to exercise 24.6 Knuth shows how to make the control sequence `\cs` into an implicit space using `\futurelet`.

```
\def\\#1\\{}\futurelet\cs\\ \\
```

You can try this out with the minimal

```
\tt
\def\\#1\\{}\futurelet\cs\\ \\
% example
a.\cs b.c
\def\empty{}
% Trying with an empty macro
a.\empty b.c
\bye
```

The obvious next port of call was the original [TeX source code](http://tex.loria.fr/tex-source/tex-source.html) itself. As Pascal is a typed language, my suspicion was that using delimiters in this manner, would conserve one string name.

Strings are defined in Part4, *String Handling*. All strings--as a matter of fact almost everything in TeX--are translated to integers and indexed. As far as TeX is concerned the name of a primitive macro or the string of an error message are no different they are all placed in `str_pool`.

When the original WEB system program called TANGLE processed the TEX.WEB file, it ouputted a Pascal program TEX.PAS (now it is CWEB and a C program) and also a string file called TEX.POOL which held all the strings used. The INITEX program read the latter file, where each string appeared as a two-digit decimal length followed by the string itself, and the information was recorded in TEX's string memory. INITEX would later on produce a binary format file which can subsequently be read at high speed by the TeX engine. (You can view the TEX.POOL file by searching for it in your distribution).

Given LaTeX's history, it made sense to use delimiters in this manner as it conserved one string.

I haven't looked carefully at the scanning routines for user-defined strings during normal typesetting operations i.e., without the source being passed through INITEX. In all probability the same mechanism is used and it is apparent that this will save some memory space, however little this is.

If one should use delimiters in such a manner is debatable as it tends to obscure the code and perhaps this is the reason for them being generally absent in packages. Rather two or three string names should be reserved for this purpose. If there is one exception I would make it would be for macros similar to the one Knuth defined:

```
 \def\\#1\\
```

It has a symmetry which one could argue has a certain beauty!

Special thanks to all the people that posted comments and especially to Lev Bishop for the additional example.

Comment: The only response I can think of to this is: "Oh what a tangled web we weave when first we practise to ... program."

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion it does provide some advantage, specifically in order to capture the contents of argument-less macros where the macro is used repetitively. One practical example is taken from [Order items in `enumerate` environment automatically](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/128297/5764) where the repetitive use of `\item` in a list environment provides a means to delineate (or parameterize) the "argument" used. In general, an item in a list has the form

```
%...
\item <some stuff>
\item <some more stuff>
%...
```

or, more aptly written as

```
%...
\item <some stuff> \item
<some more stuff>
%...
```

which allows to be captured using

```
\def\item#1\item{<do something with #1>}
```

Sure you have to find a way to manage the end of the list, since the final item has no apparent ending `\item` to match the parameter text for the newly defined `\item`. That could be achieved by appending `\item` at the end of the environment after capturing its entire contents via the help of [`environ`](http://ctan.org/pkg/environ). More details on this in the linked post.