# Make an item in itemize disappear if a condition is not met

Tags: conditionals, itemize

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\VarOne}{1500}
\begin{document}
I want this list to have item Two if VarOne is more than 1000. If it is not, this will be a two item list. By the way, I could not    get this to print VarOne with a backslash!                                                                                            
\begin{itemize}
  \item One 
  \item Two only if VarOne is more than 1000. 
  \item Three
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: `\ifnum\VarOne>1000\relax\item Two only if VarOne is more than 1000.\fi`. More latex like variations exist too.

Comment: to get `\VarOne` to print with a backslash, treat it as verbatim: `\verb+\VarOne+`.  this will work in "open" text, though not in "moving" text such as a footnote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ulrike Fischer gave a hint about `low-level` `\ifnum` query, this version uses the `\ifnumgreater` macro from the `etoolbox` package (and provides a comparison).

In my point of view, `\VarOne` should not be used as a macro but as a counter, as long only integer values are concerned.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\VarOne}{1500}


\usepackage{etoolbox}%
\begin{document}
I want this list to have item Two if VarOne is more than 1000. If it is not, this will be a two item list. By the way, I could not    get this to print \(\backslash\)VarOne with a backslash!                                                                                            
\begin{itemize}
  \item One
  \ifnumgreater{\VarOne}{1000}{\item Two only if VarOne is more than 1000.}{}
  \item Three
\end{itemize}

\renewcommand{\VarOne}{100}%
Once again -- without the 2nd argument
\begin{itemize}
  \item One 
  \ifnumgreater{\VarOne}{1000}{\item Two only if VarOne is more than 1000.}{}
  \item Three
\end{itemize}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a mildly-automated version of your request using some magic from [Order items in `enumerate` environment automatically](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/128318/5764):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ,etoolbox,multido}

% Taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/128318/5764
\makeatletter
\newcounter{varoneitem}\newcounter{listcount}[varoneitem]
\let\olditem\item% Store regular \item macro
\NewEnviron{varoneitem}[1][0]{%
  \stepcounter{varoneitem}% New orderenum environment (also resets listcount)
  \g@addto@macro{\BODY}{\item\relax\item}% Used to delimit the items; last item identified by \item\relax\item
  \def\item##1\item{% Redefine \item to capture contents
    \def\itemarg{##1}%
    \expandafter\ifx\itemarg\relax\else% Last item not reached
      \stepcounter{listcount}% Next item being processed
      \csgdef{varoneitem@\thevaroneitem @\thelistcount}{##1}% Store item in control sequence
      \expandafter\item% Recursively continue processing items
    \fi
  }
  \BODY% Process environment (save items)
  \begin{itemize}
    \multido{\i=1+1}{\value{listcount}}{%
      \ifnum\i=#1\relax
        \ifnum\VarOneCondition\relax
          \olditem \csname varoneitem@\thevaroneitem @\i\endcsname
        \fi
      \else
        \olditem \csname varoneitem@\thevaroneitem @\i\endcsname
      \fi
    }
  \end{itemize}
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\VarOne}{1500}
\newcommand{\VarOneCondition}{\VarOne>1000}

\begin{document}

I want this list to have item Two if \verb|\VarOne| is more than 1\,000. If it is not, this will be a two item list. 
By the way, I could not get this to print \verb|\VarOne| with a backslash!                                                                                            

\begin{varoneitem}[2]
  \item One 
  \item Two only if \texttt{\string\VarOne} is more than 1\,000.
  \item Three
\end{varoneitem}

\renewcommand{\VarOne}{900}
\begin{varoneitem}[2]
  \item One 
  \item Two only if \texttt{\string\VarOne} is more than 1\,000.
  \item Three
\end{varoneitem}


\end{document}
```

The idea is to process the list twice. During the first iteration, all `\item`s are collected and stored in macros. During the second iteration, items are output conditionally based on `\VarOneCondition`.

Since the process "captures" each `\item` in a macro, verbatim content should be passed differently. I've shown that in the example above as well.

The newly-created `varoneitem` environment takes an optional argument that identifies the number of the item to be suppressed conditionally. Other improvements are also possible, but I'm not sure what your end use-case is.