# Reorder long bullet list in LyX

Tags: lyx, lists, enumerate, itemize, sorting

In some document I have some long bullet lists (numbered or not numbered), for instance:

1. 2001: ...
2. 2002: ....
3. 2003: .....

but I would just like to have the list reordered in just its inverse order, so that it ends up like:

1. 2003: ...
2. 2002: ....
3. 2001: .....

this trivial example is easy, but I have lists with 200 entries. How can I do this?

Comment: I'm not sure how it would be effected in LyX-world, but this is certainly an interesting LaTeX problem :)

Comment: no, just on item and one line

Comment: plyx might be able to do this. There is a section on sorting tables and lists. see http://wiki.lyx.org/Examples/PLyXSystem

Comment: Have you heard of [`sort`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sort_(Unix))? It can sort things in a number of different ways. There's also a  [`similar command`](http://web.csulb.edu/~murdock/sort.html) for Windows....

Answer (score 2):

Using some techniques from [Order items in `enumerate` environment automatically](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/128297/5764), you can reverse the list on the LaTeX side. It will still display in sequential order as you place them within LyX, but will be reversed in the output.

Add the following to your Document > Settings... > Local Layout:

```
Format 60

Style Reverse_Enumerate
Category              List
Margin                Static
LatexType             Item_Environment
LatexName             reverseenum
NextNoIndent          1
ToggleIndent          Never
LeftMargin            MMN
LabelSep              xx
ParSkip               0.0
ItemSep               0.2
TopSep                0.7
BottomSep             0.7
ParSep                0.3
Align                 Block
AlignPossible         Block, Left
LabelType             Enumerate
LabelCounter          "enum"
HTMLTag               ol
HTMLItem              li
HTMLLabel             NONE
RefPrefix             enu
End
```

The above defines a new environment `Reverse Enumerate` that you can choose from your paragraph drop-down:

[image]

It is virtually similar to the `Enumerate` construction, only with a different name and associated with a different LaTeX environment `reverseenum` as well as the removal of the Insert > Custom Item option. Now add the definition of the `reverseenum` environment to your Document > Settings... > LaTeX Preamble:

```
% Using some ideas from
%   https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/128297/5764
\usepackage{environ}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{reverseenum}\newcounter{listcount}[reverseenum]%
\let\olditem\item% Store regular \item macro
\NewEnviron{reverseenum}{%
  \stepcounter{reverseenum}% New reverseenum environment (also resets listcount)
  \g@addto@macro{\BODY}{\item\relax\item}% Used to delimit the items; last item identified by \item\relax\item
  \def\item##1\item{% Redefine \item to capture contents
    \def\optarg{##1}%
    \expandafter\ifx\optarg\relax\else% Last item not reached
      \stepcounter{listcount}% Next item being processed
      \global\@namedef{reverseenum@\thereverseenum @\thelistcount}{##1}% Store item in control sequence
      \expandafter\item% Recursively continue processing items
    \fi
  }
  \BODY% Process environment (save items)
  \def\reverselist{% How to reverse list, recursively
    \ifnum\value{listcount}>0
      \olditem \csname reverseenum@\thereverseenum @\thelistcount\endcsname
      \addtocounter{listcount}{-1}%
      \reverselist
    \fi
  }
  \enumerate\reverselist\endenumerate% Process items
}
\makeatother
```

The above definition processes the list once, storing each `\item` in a specially-named macro. Once the entire environment is processed and the `\item`s stored, it re-processes the list by setting the now-stored `\item`s in reverse order, stepping backward through the list of specially-named macros.

To that end, consider the following LyX input:

[image]

The first list is set under `Enumerate`. The second list is set under `Reverse Enumerate`. It produces the following PDF output:

[image]

It would be trivial to modify the above to work for an `Itemize` list as well.