# Delimiting-a-macro-with-itself-chain

Tags: macros, tex-core, syntax

Reading [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14685/delimiting-a-macro-argument-with-the-macro-itself) and the answer of @Werner made me think about if it is possible to have chains of self-delimiting macros like `\XX abc \XX def \XX xyz` or lets say

```
\begin{someenv}
  \XX abc
  \XX def
  \XX xyz
\end{someenv}
```

The original definition will obviously fail here - insufficent number fo `\XX`s. So, a first step towards an easy redefinition of `\XX` could be to say

```
\def\XX#1\XX{do sth with #1\\ \XX}
```

The problem now is to terminate this chain in an elegant way. A rather rude and *not* desiderable way is shown in the MWE below.

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\XX#1\XX{do sth with #1\\ \XX}

\newenvironment{someenv}{\center}{\endcenter}

\def\abc{def}

\begin{document}
\begin{someenv}
  \XX xyz
  \XX abc
  \XX \abc
  \let\XX\empty %this is the bad guy that needs to be busted
\end{someenv}
\end{document}
```

Comment: So what's the question here?

Comment: @Werner, "The problem now is to terminate this chain in an elegant way."

Comment: You need to supply some ending constraint, otherwise there's no way to stop it. The ending constraint may be explicit, but mostly its implicit in the form of a environment end, like in your example. It's already elegant (in my opinion) as the user doesn't see it or have to worry about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't really do it unless you grab the token list you need as an argument.

Here's a possibility using `environ`; usage of `expl3` is not necessary, but it provides a good framework for doing the desired job later.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ,expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewEnviron{collectitems}
 {
  % clear the sequence
  \seq_clear:N \l_ruben_collected_items_seq
  % process the body
  \exp_last_unbraced:No \ruben_collect_item:nw \BODY \item \q_stop
  % do something with the sequence
  \seq_show:N \l_ruben_collected_items_seq
 }
\seq_new:N \l_ruben_collected_items_seq
\cs_new_protected:Npn \ruben_collect_item:nw #1 \item #2 \q_stop
 {
  \seq_put_right:Nx \l_ruben_collected_items_seq { \tl_trim_spaces:n { #1 } }
  \tl_if_empty:nF { #2 }
   {
    \ruben_collect_item:nw #2 \q_stop
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{collectitems}
\item Apple
\item Banana
\item Cherry
\end{collectitems}

\begin{collectitems}
\end{collectitems}

\end{document}
```

The body is collected in `\BODY`, which is expanded before prepending `\ruben_collect_item:nw` and appending `\item \q_stop`. The function `\ruben_collect_item:nw` is executed at every `\item`, until `\item` is immediately followed by `\q_stop`. The items are put in a sequence; the first item in the sequence will contain whatever is before the first `\item` token and can be used to check whether an `\item` token is actually seen, as the example shows.

The output on the terminal is

```
The sequence \l_ruben_collected_items_seq contains the items (without outer braces):
>  {}
>  {Apple}
>  {Banana}
>  {Cherry}.
<recently read> }

l.31 \end{collectitems}

? 
The sequence \l_ruben_collected_items_seq contains the items (without outer braces):
>  {}.
<recently read> }

l.34 \end{collectitems}
```

Of course you will do something more useful with the sequence.

---

A “translation” into classical commands for a description environment that adapts the left margin to the width of the widest label.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ,enumitem}

\newlength\rubenwidth
\NewEnviron{xdescription}{%
  \expandafter\rubenprocess\BODY\item\rubenprocess
  \begin{itemize}[labelwidth=\rubenwidth,leftmargin=\rubenwidth,align=left,font=\bfseries]
  \BODY
  \end{itemize}
}
\makeatletter
\def\rubenprocess#1#2\item#3\rubenprocess{% #1 is always \item
  \ruben@item#2\ruben@item
  \if\relax\detokenize{#3}\relax
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi
  {\rubenprocess\item#3\rubenprocess}%
}
\def\ruben@item[#1]#2\ruben@item{%
  \settowidth\@tempdima{\bfseries#1}%
  \ifdim\rubenwidth<\@tempdima\rubenwidth=\@tempdima\fi
}

\begin{document}

\begin{xdescription}
\item[Apple] a round fruit
\item[Banana] not so round fruit
\item[Strawberry] small fruit with some more words
  to get the text into two lines; will we succeed?
\end{xdescription}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Many variations of the idea are possible.

Comment: Is it `:nw` or `:ww` (or `:w`)?

Comment: I am still really bad with xpl3. If it isn't too time consuming, could you show in addition how your solution would work without using LaTeX3 stuff?

Comment: @Ruben It mostly depends on what you want to do with the items.

Comment: Sure! Suppose I want to measure them with `\settowidth` and store them in a token register.

Comment: @Ruben Dinner time. Stay tuned.

Comment: This is prety close. I noticed one thing: When I cancel the optional argument from one of the `\item`s the code refuses to work properly. It clearly has to do with the last definition, or what do you think?

Comment: @Ruben The optional argument in a description list is not really optional. Without a real specification from you, I devised an example.

Comment: Ok, got it. If you like you can have a look at the application I had in mind: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149273/maintaining-structure-workbook-style/214547#214547

Comment: I think the last mentioned issue can be solved with the end-of-line char. So, you don't need to invest more energy here. In fact, I am alredy really happy with what is here alredy!

Answer (score 3):

Is something like this what you want?

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{someenv}{\par\centering}{\par}
\newenvironment{XX}{\endXX\bfseries\itshape Do sth with\ }{\mdseries\upshape\par}
\let\notXX\endXX
\def\abc{ABC}
\begin{document}
before
\begin{someenv}
  \XX xyz 
  \XX abc
  \XX \abc 
  \notXX not under \verb|\XX| control % USE \notXX TO FORCE BREAK FROM \XX CONTROL
  \XX ending line
\end{someenv}
after
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can get fancy and make the "something" that `\XX` does vary with the iteration of `\XX` within the environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{instance}
\newenvironment{someenv}{\par\centering\setcounter{instance}{0}}{\par}
\newenvironment{XX}{\endXX\bfseries\itshape\stepcounter{instance}
    Iteration \theinstance: Do sth with\ }
  {\mdseries\upshape\par}
\let\notXX\endXX
\def\abc{ABC}
\begin{document}
before
\begin{someenv}
  \XX xyz 
  \XX abc
  \XX \abc 
  \notXX not under \verb|\XX| control % USE \notXX TO FORCE BREAK FROM \XX CONTROL
  \XX ending line
\end{someenv}
after
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! To answer your question. (The `\notXX` function is neat :) Now, I have to check if it is appliable to other cases. For instance, like the one I described in the comments of egregs answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the code from [Macro parameter delimited by more than one delimiter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200452/macro-parameter-delimited-by-more-than-one-delimiter). This code defines the `\seplist` macro. Its argument is the list of separators. The separators in your example are `\XX` or `\end` (with space before this). The definition of `\XX` looks like:

```
\def\XXa#1{... macro with normal #1 parameter\par\sepused}
\def\XX{\seplist{{ \XX}{ \end}}\XXa}

\begin{someenv}
   \XX abc
   \XX def
   \XX xyz
\end{someenv}
```

Comment: Altough it's a “inside link”, this site prefers to have self contained answers. So it would be better if you include the `\seplist` definition in this answer.